# placeNumbers should return an ordering of the numbers such that the conditions encoded in the vector of Boolean values are met

Tags: c++

placeNumbers is a function that should take a vector of n integers and a vector of n−1 Boolean values as input and return a vector of n integers. placeNumbers should return an ordering of the numbers such that the conditions encoded in the vector of Boolean values are met. A value in the Boolean vector will be true if
the number that would be to its left is less than the right that would be to its right, and false otherwise. It may be assumed that the vector will be in ascending order.

I got an error at the end where tempNumbers[i + 1] = smaller.pop(); where it said "a value of type "void" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int" "

I dont know how to fix this error and I'm not sure if my code work correctly for the requirement of the homework. This is my first course that I use C++ so please dont yell at me if I did something stupid :(

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include "csce310assgnmnt02prt01.h"
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

vector<int> placeNumbers(vector<int> numbers, vector<bool> signs){
vector<int> tempNumbers;
vector <int> sortedNumbers;
std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end(), sortedNumbers);

int nbigger = accumulate(signs.begin(), signs.end(), 0);

int startIndex = sizeof(numbers) - (nbigger + 1);

std::stack<int>smaller;
for (int i = 0; i < startIndex; i++){
    smaller.push(sortedNumbers[i]);
}

std::queue<int>bigger;
for (int i = startIndex + 1; i <sizeof(sortedNumbers); i++){
    bigger.push(sortedNumbers[i]);
}


for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(signs); i++){
    if (signs[i] == 0){
        tempNumbers[i + 1] = smaller.pop();

    }
    if (signs[i] == 1){
        tempNumbers[i + 1] = bigger.pop();
    }
    numbers = tempNumbers;
}
return numbers;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`pop()` doesn't return the value, it just removes the top of the stack and returns `void`. You need to call `top()` to get the value and then `pop()` to remove it. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/top/) you can read the doc of `top()`
 and [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/pop/) the doc of `pop()`